# inspect text not showing in dev tools

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate text field using selenium, when I try to inspect the object its not showing in dev tools
-text fields-

Industry : ***CGS-AGRIBUSINESS***,

Client NAME  : **AB VOLVO**

text name(Industry) I can see in dev tools but the text value not visible(**CGS-AGRIBUSINESS**), I want to verify the text ex : **AB VOLVO**, whether it is present or not

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eqdf.png)

Comment: Click on the `<input>` field, additional field will get added to the HTML.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I click on the <input> field nothing getting added to HTML, could you please help more elaborately ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Chrome devtools, and navigate to a tab called `Properties`. See the screenshot below.

[image: Properties tab]

In that tab, see if there is a property called `value`. I think you will be able to see the text that you want to verify `CGS-AGRIBUSINESS` in that value.

Now to retrieve the text from the `value` attribute, just use the `getAttribute` method to get the attribute value.

Here is a rough syntax

```
driver.findElement(your_xpath_or_any_locator_here).getAttribute('value')
```

This has already been explained in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70212658/text-in-text-input-fields-in-ui-angular-application-not-visible-in-devtools-sele) question.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even read the question, but your answer was the answer to the question *I* had. There was a text area in an internal site's page that I could not get the text out of (it was read-only, partially displayed and the selection was disabled). I found the contents in the `value` property - again, BIG THANK YOU. I really needed that text!